# C Scanf Command Won't Run

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am a new learner to the C language. I am trying to figure out how to use scanf. This is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char lastInitial;
    printf("What is your last inital?");
    scanf(" %c", &lastInitial);
}
```

When I run this code (I'm using VS Code), it shows that the file is running, but nothing shows up. When I go to the top to click the run button again, it says this code is already running. If I stop the run, delete the scanf line and run again, the file runs and displays "What is your last inital?" I am confused as to why adding scanf to the file stops the printf and doesn't allow any user input.

Comment: Try adding a '\n' to the end of that `printf`.

Comment: I ran the OPs code, with no changes on linux and it worked perfectly.

Comment: do an fflush or perhaps, a getchar() before the scanf.

Answer (score 4):

You might have run into a little intricacy with how `printf` works. When you run `printf("What is your last inital?");`, this text does not end with a newline (`\n`) character. As a result, some environments might not display it right away, delaying it until you `printf` a complete line or until the program ends. This is done for efficiency, since the internal steps to actually get output to your screen are a bit expensive.

When you remove the `scanf`, the program ends right after the printf; as the program is ending any text that's still waiting to be displayed gets sent to the screen by the built-in shutdown routines in the C standard library. However, when the `scanf` is included, the text gets buffered/delayed, and doesn't ever get sent to the screen sine the program is stalled waiting for user input. You can force the output to be sent immediately using a newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char lastInitial;
    printf("What is your last inital?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &lastInitial);
}
```

Or if you don't want a newline, you can tell the C standard library to explicitly send all output text right away:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char lastInitial;
    printf("What is your last inital?");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(" %c", &lastInitial);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program, you should switch from "OUTPUT" to "TERMINAL".
You need to install the "Code Runner" extension.

Then go to `File-->Preferences-->Settings` in the search write `code runner`, and below will appear some settings of code runner, you need to find `Run In Terminal`, and turn it on.

THAT'S ALL :)